# How to find all occurrencces of String expressions directly compared to null?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

As a part of code quality efforts in special contexts we want to avoid comparing String expressions directly to null. Is there a way to find all such expressions (stringExp == null; stringExp != null; and v.v.)?

Answer (score 0):

This is something that PMD (https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_extending_writing_java_rules.html) is good for.

Comment: Isn't PMD a pure AST parser? Is PMD able to evaluate the type of a method call expression like _if(foo().bar().func() == null)_ ?

Comment: It's been a while, but I believe once you've descended into an equality expression, you can get the types of both sides, and if one side is a constant, that should also be deducible, along with its value.

Comment: Would mean, PMD has compile time information (class hierarchy, referenced types). But anyway, I'll give it a try.